# In React, how do I instantiate a class without a constructor in my unit test?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, constructor, instantiation

I'm using React 16.13.0.  I have the below class (Missions.ts) ...

```
class Missions {

  repo() : MissionRepository {
    return getRepository(Mission) as MissionRepository;
  }

  async getAll() : Promise<Mission[]>  {
    return this.repo().find();
  }
    ...
  async removeVolunteerFromMission(missionId: string) {
    const missions = this.repo();
    const mission = await missions.findById(missionId);
    mission.volunteerId = '';
    mission.status = MissionStatus.unassigned;
    return missions.update(mission);
  }
  ...
}

export default new Missions();
```

I'm trying to write some unit tests for the methods but I'm having trouble figuring out how to instantiate my class.  I have tried the below ...

```
import React from "react";
import { CustomRepository, getRepository } from 'fireorm';
import { BaseRepository } from './BaseRepository'
import { Mission } from './schema';
import { Missions } from './Missions';

describe('Missions', () => {
  describe('#removeVolunteerFromMission', () => {
    const missionId = "1234";
    const mission = new Mission();

    beforeEach(() => {
      const mockFindById = jest.fn();
      BaseRepository.prototype.findById = mockFindById;
      mockFindById.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(mission));

      const mockUpdate = jest.fn();
      BaseRepository.prototype.update = mockUpdate;
      mockUpdate.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(mission));
    });

    it('unassigns volunteer', () => {
      const obj = new Missions();
      obj.removeVolunteerFromMission(missionId)
      expect(mockFindById).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(mockUpdate).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(mission.volunteer).toBe(null);
    });
  });
});
```

However upon running my test using "hpm test", I'm getting this error

```
TypeError: _Missions.Missions is not a constructor
```

on the line

```
const obj = new Missions()
```

How do I instantiate my class within the test?

Comment: how are you exporting your class?

Comment: Oops, edited my question -- like this, "export default new Missions();"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're exporting an instance of `Missions` class and not the class itself, and you cannot instantiate an instance again. So export only the class and then instantiate it where you want to use it.

```
export default Missions;
```

Instantiate it where you want to use it:

```
const missions = new Missions();
```

Also default export are imported without the curly brackets, so do this:

```
import Missions from './Missions';
```

Comment: Thanks but it is not an option to change my "export default ..." syntax in the Missions.ts file.  I have to work with it as is.

Comment: Then import missions like this, `import missions from './Missions';` and then don't instantiate it. Just start using it: `missions.removeVolunteerFromMission(missionId)`;